# LibreOffice (Calc) | Search & Replace | unable to look for 'comments'

Tags: search, find-and-replace, libreoffice-calc, comments

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> enables the SearchBar (quick search)
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> brings up Find & Replace dialog (more options)

I'm unable to find a way to look for comments that are within with a cell (with ability to search all sheets by default).

Because Using *Navigator* (<kbd>F5</kbd>) is not efficient enough and you **have** to match 'FirstCase' basis. Working with a lot of sheets and cells, makes it hard to search with a FirstCase basis.

Now there is the option to `Find & Replace` > `Other options` > `Search in: Notes`, but that doesn't work either, in fact there is no way of knowing what notes even are.

How do I search for comments in LibreOffice Calc?

## Vocabulary

**FirstCase-basis** (not LastCase) is only being able to match the matching characters from the beginning of a line and nothing after the first character.

e.g. searching for "Blue Whale", instead you type "*whale*" your not able to find it unless you type "*Blu*" (it being case sensitive, which is why *Navigator* is a horrible concept).

Comment: What do you mean by "'FirstCase' basis"?

Comment: Is `Find & replace` -> `Search options` -> `Search in: Notes` what you're looking for?

Comment: @tohuwawohu I've tried that, but it doesn't work. It won't search any text matched within comment.

Comment: Hmm - awwww - seems to be a [bug known since mid-2013](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=65334) :-(( so i fear, currently, there's no solution for this. You may subscribe to that bug so it may receive more attention...